# How to install Jenkins on Windows 11?

Tags: jenkins, windows-11, local-security-policy

When setup install in the Service Logon Credentials step, I select Run service as local or domain user and when Test Credentials always gets `Invalid Logon`.
[image]

In this Jenkins documentation link [invalid service logon credentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/windows/#invalid-service-logon-credentials), there is something to do in `Local Security Policy` but I can't find it on my OS (Windows 11). Been looking for several ways like in the following [link](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-local-security-policy/) but still can't find it. Can anyone help fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 11, Home Single Language edition (aka Win11 Home) and the problem was solved after download and install gpedit.msc (Group Policy Editor) before you can use `Local Security Policy`. You can follow the steps from [here](https://www.dealntech.com/fix-windows-11-cannot-find-gpedit-msc-group-policy-editor/).

Test by looking for it if the install has been completed, as shown below:
[image]